# How to unmount component/re-render while navigating one screen to another in drawer navigator in react native?

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

I have tried with `unmountOnBlur:true`. I have 3 screens(**A** **B** and **C**). In this case, whenever the user goes back to **B** screen from **C**, then **B** screen will be unmounted. and mounted back again with fresh data. I don't want to re-render **B** screen while go back from **C** screen. I just want to re-render **B** screen when the user navigate to **A** screen to **B**.

I also tried 'focus' event but getting same behaviour.

```
const unsubscribe = props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case `unmountOnBlur:true` will not work because you want diff. behaviour on diff navigation actions.

so you can use

```
    const unsubscribe = props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      });

    const unsubscribe = props.navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
       //clear your listeners/state here
    });
```

If you are using functional component the you can use `useIsFocused()` hook

```
 const isFocused = useIsFocused()

useEffect(() => {
    if (!isFocused) return //when blue

    //when focues

    
  }, [isFocused])
```